# Android project consuming .Net Core 2.0 web api

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create my first Android project in visual studio and also creating a web api with .NET Core 2.0. I was able to test my web api using Chrome extension Restlet Client and it is returning the data.

I could not find an example where an Android project (in C#) is consuming a .NET Core web api. So, I tried to do it myself.

I first created a .NET Core 2.0 web api and then added a blank Android project in the same solution. I then referenced the web api in my android project and I am trying to do a build.

I am getting the following error:

> Project 'C:\Users....\MyCoreWebService.csproj' targets
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that
>   targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0'.   MyAndroidApp

I may be completely wrong but this is what I am trying to do in my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private DbContextOptions<MyContext> db = new DbContextOptions<MyContext>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        MyContext context = new MyContext(db);
        TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Employee employee = context.employees.SingleAsync().Result;

        tv.Text = employee.employeeName;
    }
}
```

Please suggest on how to consume a .Net core web api into an android app using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Consuming a .net core web api in Android is no different than consuming any http service so just look for how to do http requests in general.

Comment: You don’t reference the WebAPI project in the Android project. You consume it via HTTP calls. Remove the reference and move on with learning.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction. I also took the help of the following link: [link]https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#rest[/link]